# strcmp behaviour

Tags: c, string, strcmp

When I run the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int p = 0;

    p = strcmp(NULL,"foo");

    return 0;
}
```

I get segmentation fault. echo $? says 139. But when I run

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int p = 0;

    strcmp(NULL,"foo"); // Note removed assignment

    return 0;
}
```

I don't get any segmentation fault. Could someone please throw some light?

Here is my gcc info:

```
> gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-8)
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You are probably using optimization options when compiling. Since the result of `strcmp()` in the second snippet is ignored the compiler eliminates this function call and this is why your program does not crash. This call can be eliminated only because `strcmp()` is an intrinsic function, the compiler is aware that this function does not have any side effects.

Comment: Well, I did not do any compiler settings to turn on optimization, however it does it automatically. You were spot on.

Comment: gcc does SSA which works even with no optimizations enabled. SSA can remove dead code. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form

Answer (score 6):

You need to:

- Include the proper headers, or declare functions manually. For `strcmp()`, you need `<string.h>`.
- Not pass an invalid pointer such as NULL to `strcmp()`, since it doesn't protect against it and will dereference the pointer, thus causing undefined behavior in your program.

Comment: The OP knows that NULL is invalid, but is asking why the two cases are different.

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing is undefined. `strcmp` requires valid pointers to null-terminated strings.

`NULL` is not a pointer to a null-terminated string.