# Memory fault with the use of const char*?

Tags: c++, linux, environment-variables

Hi I'm working with C++ on Linux platform, i have to get the value of a environment variable(user defined) and use it further. 
Following is the code I'm using,

```
const char *show_line = getenv ("MY_SHOW_LINES");

bool myFlag = (strcmp(show_line, "1") == 0) ? false : true;
```

Above code executes properly when i set the value of environment variable(MY_SHOW_LINES) equal to 1 but when i unset the value of it(i.e. unset MY_SHOW_LINES).
Above code gives memory fault.
Any suggestion on above UN-expected behavior??
Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932848/strcmp-behaviour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass a NULL pointer to `strcmp`, you get undefined behavior, in this case a very likely crash.

Are you aware that pointers can be `NULL`, i.e. purposely invalid?

You should guard against this possibility:

```
bool myFlag = false; // set default value
if ( show_line != NULL ) {
    myFlag = ( strcmp(show_line, "1") != 0 ); // "? false : true" same as NOT…
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page,

> The getenv() function returns a pointer to the value in the
>   environment, or NULL if there is no match.

So if it doesn't exist, it returns `NULL`, which causes digestion problems for `strcmp()`.